# Solucion al problema de JSON.parse

Tags: json

¡Buenas noches!; tengo un sistema de compra y venta de artículos en el archivo "cliente.js" que dentro de mi proyecto esta en la carpeta (/vistas/js) ya que el proyecto esta dividido en varias partes; este el mi código "clientes.js"

```html
var tabla;

var tabla_en_ventas;

//Función que se ejecuta al inicio
function init(){
 
 listar();

 //llama la lista de clientes en ventana modal en ventas.php
    listar_en_ventas();

  //cuando se da click al boton submit entonces se ejecuta la funcion guardaryeditar(e);
 $("#cliente_form").on("submit",function(e)
 {

  guardaryeditar(e); 
 })
    
    //cambia el titulo de la ventana modal cuando se da click al boton
 $("#add_button").click(function(){
   
   $(".modal-title").text("Agregar Cliente");
  
   });

 
}

//Función limpiar
/*IMPORTANTE: no limpiar el campo oculto del id_usuario, sino no se registra
el cliente*/
function limpiar()
{
 
 $('#cedula').val("");
 $('#nombre').val("");
 $('#apellido').val("");
 $('#telefono').val("");
 $('#email').val("");
 $('#direccion').val("");
 $('#estado').val("");
 $('#cedula_cliente').val("");
}


//Función Listar
function listar()
{
 tabla=$('#cliente_data').dataTable(
 {
  "aProcessing": true,//Activamos el procesamiento del datatables
     "aServerSide": true,//Paginación y filtrado realizados por el servidor
     dom: 'Bfrtip',//Definimos los elementos del control de tabla
     buttons: [            
              'copyHtml5',
              'excelHtml5',
              'csvHtml5',
              'pdf'
          ],
  "ajax":
    {
     url: '../ajax/cliente.php?op=listar',
     type : "get",
     dataType : "json",      
     error: function(e){
      console.log(e.responseText); 
     }
    },
  "bDestroy": true,
  "responsive": true,
  "bInfo":true,
  "iDisplayLength": 10,//Por cada 10 registros hace una paginación
     "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],//Ordenar (columna,orden)
     
     "language": {
 
       "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
    
       "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
    
       "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
    
       "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
    
       "sInfo":           "Mostrando un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
    
       "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando un total de 0 registros",
    
       "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
    
       "sInfoPostFix":    "",
    
       "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
    
       "sUrl":            "",
    
       "sInfoThousands":  ",",
    
       "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
    
       "oPaginate": {
    
           "sFirst":    "Primero",
    
           "sLast":     "Último",
    
           "sNext":     "Siguiente",
    
           "sPrevious": "Anterior"
    
       },
    
       "oAria": {
    
           "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
    
           "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
    
       }

      }//cerrando language
        
 }).DataTable();
}


//Mostrar datos del cliente en la ventana modal 
function mostrar(cedula_cliente)
{
 $.post("../ajax/cliente.php?op=mostrar",{cedula_cliente : cedula_cliente}, function(data, status)
 {
  data = JSON.parse(data);

   //alert(data.cedula);

     console.log(data);
  
    $('#clienteModal').modal('show');
    $('#cedula').val(cedula_cliente);
    $('#nombre').val(data.nombre);
    $('#apellido').val(data.apellido);
    $('#telefono').val(data.telefono);
    $('#email').val(data.correo);
    $('#direccion').val(data.direccion);
    $('#estado').val(data.estado);
    $('.modal-title').text("Editar Cliente");
    $('#cedula_cliente').val(cedula_cliente);
   
    
  });
        
        
 }

 //la funcion guardaryeditar(e); se llama cuando se da click al boton submit
function guardaryeditar(e)
{
 e.preventDefault(); //No se activará la acción predeterminada del evento
 var formData = new FormData($("#cliente_form")[0]);


  $.ajax({
   url: "../ajax/cliente.php?op=guardaryeditar",
      type: "POST",
      data: formData,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,

      success: function(datos)
      {                    
            /*bootbox.alert(datos);           
            mostrarform(false);
            tabla.ajax.reload();*/

           //alert(datos);
                 
                 /*imprimir consulta en la consola debes hacer un print_r($_POST) al final del metodo 
                    y si se muestran los valores es que esta bien, y se puede imprimir la consulta desde el metodo
                    y se puede ver en la consola o desde el mensaje de alerta luego pegar la consulta en phpmyadmin*/
           console.log(datos);

             $('#cliente_form')[0].reset();
    $('#clienteModal').modal('hide');

    $('#resultados_ajax').html(datos);
    $('#cliente_data').DataTable().ajax.reload();
    
                limpiar();
     
      }

  });
       
}


//EDITAR ESTADO DEL CLIENTE
//importante:id_cliente, est se envia por post via ajax


    function cambiarEstado(id_cliente, est){


 bootbox.confirm("¿Está Seguro de cambiar de estado?", function(result){
  if(result)
  {

   
   $.ajax({
    url:"../ajax/cliente.php?op=activarydesactivar",
     method:"POST",
    //data:dataString,
    //toma el valor del id y del estado
    data:{id_cliente:id_cliente, est:est},
    //cache: false,
    //dataType:"html",
    success: function(data){
                 
                  $('#cliente_data').DataTable().ajax.reload();
       
       }

   });

    }

   });//bootbox



   }


    //Función Listar
function listar_en_ventas(){

 tabla_en_ventas=$('#lista_clientes_data').dataTable(
 {
  "aProcessing": true,//Activamos el procesamiento del datatables
     "aServerSide": true,//Paginación y filtrado realizados por el servidor
     dom: 'Bfrtip',//Definimos los elementos del control de tabla
     buttons: [            
              'copyHtml5',
              'excelHtml5',
              'csvHtml5',
              'pdf'
          ],
  "ajax":
    {
     url: '../ajax/cliente.php?op=listar_en_ventas',
     type : "get",
     dataType : "json",      
     error: function(e){
      console.log(e.responseText); 
     }
    },
  "bDestroy": true,
  "responsive": true,
  "bInfo":true,
  "iDisplayLength": 10,//Por cada 10 registros hace una paginación
     "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],//Ordenar (columna,orden)
     
     "language": {
 
       "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
    
       "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
    
       "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
    
       "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
    
       "sInfo":           "Mostrando un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
    
       "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando un total de 0 registros",
    
       "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
    
       "sInfoPostFix":    "",
    
       "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
    
       "sUrl":            "",
    
       "sInfoThousands":  ",",
    
       "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
    
       "oPaginate": {
    
           "sFirst":    "Primero",
    
           "sLast":     "Último",
    
           "sNext":     "Siguiente",
    
           "sPrevious": "Anterior"
    
       },
    
       "oAria": {
    
           "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
    
           "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
    
       }

      }//cerrando language
        
 }).DataTable();
}


//AUTOCOMPLETAR DATOS DEL CLIENTE EN VENTAS
 

   function agregar_registro(id_cliente,est){

      
  $.ajax({
   url:"../ajax/cliente.php?op=buscar_cliente",
   method:"POST",
   data:{id_cliente:id_cliente,est:est},
   dataType:"json",
   success:function(data)
   {
               
             
            /*si el cliente esta activo entonces se ejecuta, de lo contrario 
            el formulario no se envia y aparecerá un mensaje */
            if(data.estado){

    $('#modalCliente').modal('hide');
    $('#cedula').val(data.cedula_cliente);
    $('#nombre').val(data.nombre);
    $('#apellido').val(data.apellido);
    $('#direccion').val(data.direccion);
    $('#id_cliente').val(id_cliente);
    

            } else{
                
                bootbox.alert(data.error);
               


             } //cierre condicional error

                        
    
   }
  })
 
    }

     //ELIMINAR CLIENTE

  function eliminar(id_cliente){

   
     bootbox.confirm("¿Está Seguro de eliminar el cliente?", function(result){
  if(result)
  {

    $.ajax({
     url:"../ajax/cliente.php?op=eliminar_cliente",
     method:"POST",
     data:{id_cliente:id_cliente},

     success:function(data)
     {
      //alert(data);
      $("#resultados_ajax").html(data);
      $("#cliente_data").DataTable().ajax.reload();
     }
    });

        }

   });//bootbox


   }



init();
```

Pero al ejecutar la Vista HTML Bootstrap Clientes.php; sale un error al editar

[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7TPV.jpg)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<?php

   require_once("../config/conexion.php");

    if(isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){
       
       
?>



<?php
 
  require_once("header.php");

?>
  <!--Contenido-->
      <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
      <div class="content-wrapper">        
        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">
             
             <div id="resultados_ajax"></div>

             <h2>Listado de Clientes</h2>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="box">
                    <div class="box-header with-border">
                          <h1 class="box-title">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="add_button" onclick="limpiar()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#clienteModal"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Nuevo Cliente</button></h1>
                        <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.box-header -->
                    <!-- centro -->
                    <div class="panel-body table-responsive">
                          
                          <table id="cliente_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">

                            <thead>
                              
                                <tr>
                                  
                                <th>Cédula</th>
                                <th>Nombres</th>
                                <th>Apellidos</th>
                                <th>Teléfono</th>
                                <th>Correo</th>
                                <th>Dirección</th>
                                <th>Fecha</th>
                                <th>Estado</th>
                                <th width="10%">Editar</th>
                                <th width="10%">Eliminar</th>



                                </tr>
                            </thead>

                            <tbody>
                              

                            </tbody>


                          </table>
                     
                    </div>
                  
                    <!--Fin centro -->
                  </div><!-- /.box -->
              </div><!-- /.col -->
          </div><!-- /.row -->
      </section><!-- /.content -->

    </div><!-- /.content-wrapper -->
  <!--Fin-Contenido-->
    
   <!--FORMULARIO VENTANA MODAL-->
  
<div id="clienteModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="cliente_form">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Agregar Cliente</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">


               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputText3" class="col-lg-1 control-label">Cédula</label>

                  <div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-1">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cedula" name="cedula" placeholder="Cédula" required pattern="[0-9]{0,15}">
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputText1" class="col-lg-1 control-label">Nombres</label>

                  <div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-1">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombres" required pattern="^[a-zA-Z_áéíóúñ\s]{0,30}$">
                  </div>
              </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputText1" class="col-lg-1 control-label">Apellidos</label>

                  <div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-1">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellido" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellidos" required pattern="^[a-zA-Z_áéíóúñ\s]{0,30}$">
                  </div>
              </div>

               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputText4" class="col-lg-1 control-label">Teléfono</label>

                  <div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-1">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefono" name="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono" required pattern="[0-9]{0,15}">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputText4" class="col-lg-1 control-label">Correo</label>

                  <div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-1">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo" required="required">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputText5" class="col-lg-1 control-label">Dirección</label>
                 
                 <div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-1">
                 <textarea class="form-control  col-lg-5" rows="3" id="direccion" name="direccion"  placeholder="Direccion ..." required pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9_áéíóúñ°\s]{0,200}$"></textarea>
                 </div>
                 
              </div>

               
               

               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputText4" class="col-lg-1 control-label">Estado</label>

                  <div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-1">

                      <select class="form-control" id="estado" name="estado" required>
                      <option value="">-- Selecciona estado --</option>
                      <option value="1" selected>Activo</option>
                      <option value="0">Inactivo</option>
                    </select>

                  </div>
                </div>

          
          </div>
                 <!--modal-body-->

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <input type="hidden" name="id_usuario" id="id_usuario" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["id_usuario"];?>"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="id_cliente" id="id_cliente"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="cedula_cliente" id="cedula_cliente"/>
          

          <button type="submit" name="action" id="#" class="btn btn-success pull-left" value="Add"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Guardar </button>

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> Cerrar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
 <!--FIN FORMULARIO VENTANA MODAL-->

<?php

  require_once("footer.php");
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/clientes.js"></script>



<?php
   
  } else {

        header("Location:".Conectar::ruta()."vistas/index.php");

  }

  

?>
```

Comment: Basicamente el problema se debe a que tu JSON no esta bien construido. Intenta pasar tu json por un validador como [JSONLINT](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: ¿Lograste solucionar el problema?